# Any way to play an .mkv file in the browser?

Tags: video, browser, codec, matroska

Im building an admin interface for a site, and it would be a great benefit if I could play mkv files in the browser, instead of downloading and then playing them. This doesn't have to be a mainstream technology, since only 3 people will be using the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/) can install a plugin for Mozilla, so you can actually play everything VLC can play, but in your browser. Check out the [documentation on this plugin](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch07.html):

> VLC can also be embedded in a web browser ! For the moment, this function is only available with [Mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/) under GNU/Linux. An experimental plugin is also available for Mac OS X and Microsft Windows.

Comment: Won't the plugin still download the file first and then play it? Or does the file actually get streamed to the client (although I think you would need something on the server for that to work)?

Comment: the content of the file has to be streamed to the decoder ALWAYS. if that decoder is vlc or flash doesnt matter. and i think the problem this time is more the 'download the file, save it somewhere, hit the right icon to finally play it' than the transport of the content (intranet maybe?).

Comment: This works.... kind of. Its not very reliable, and it freezes after a few seconds, when playing high def files especially. But I guess it will have to do.